# Minecraft Missing Server jvm (Have JRE Installed)

Tags: java, server, minecraft

I recently installed the JDK, and ever since then, running my Minecraft server through the JRE hasn't worked (returning the error "Missing `server' JVM (Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll.)"). A question eerily similar to this one has been asked on here before, but it seems that the poster simply hadn't installed the JRE. Could this be an error with set path in the cmd?

To clarify: the server was working just fine for a while, and I never turned it off. Recently, my power went out, and as such, it turned off. In the interim between turning it on and the power going out, I installed the JDK and ran some trivial Java applications through the cmd. I *think* this is the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Reinstall the Java 7 server JRE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returned the error:

> Missing `server' JVM (Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll.)

Clearly stating it is looking for Java**jre7**\bin\server\jvm.dll

Try and install jre7 and it should work.